# mysql fetch data corrosponding to email in another table

Tags: php, mysql

hello all i am working on a project where i need to fetch all the data from a mysql table where if the email matches with any of the emails in an array..
array is produced by another table ..
currently my code is ..

```
$selectfrnds=mysql_query("select sender_id,receiver_id from fk_friends where   (sender_id='$email' or receiver_id='$email') and friendtofriend='freq' ");
while($myallfriends=mysql_fetch_array($selectfrnds)){


                        $friendis=$myallfriends['sender_id'];

                $detailsoffriend=mysql_query("select * from fk_views where (email='$friendis' or onprf_of='$friendis') and (views !='' or uploadpic !='') order by id asc  ");
                while($selecteddatais=mysql_fetch_array($detailsoffriend)){


//displaying the posts here ...
}}
```

The problem here is this code causes grouping i.e it gets all the posts of one email then all the posts of another email and so on . but i want to get it as in database ,i do not want grouping..

$email is the email in session.

any help please .....

Comment: what do you mean grouping? can you provide output? i am having difficulties understanding your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get it in one query instead of hitting the database over and over again. Your query might look like

```sql
SELECT v.* 
  FROM fk_views v JOIN fk_friends f
    ON (v.email = f.sender_id OR v.onprf_of = f.sender_id)
 WHERE (f.sender_id = '$email' OR f.receiver_id = '$email') 
   AND f.friendtofriend = 'freq'
   AND (v.views !='' OR v.uploadpic !='') 
-- GROUP BY v.id -- it's unclear without seeing your schema and sample data but you might need GROUP BY to eliminate duplicates
 ORDER BY v.id
```